# How i can display blob elements is same row with php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to display images in same row,but i can display only under each other. I tried in css display: inline-block; but dont working. Any idea what i need to do? Thanks

The code for display images:

```
require_once 'dbConfig.php'; 

$result = $db->query("SELECT image FROM images ORDER BY uploaded DESC"); 
?>

<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){ ?> 

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
    <a class="lightbox">

    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 


    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" width="250", " height="250">';}?>



<?php }else{ ?> 
    <p class="status error">Image(s) not found...</p> 
<?php } ?>  


</a>    
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your solution in case someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you large col is only 3.
[Inspect element result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeTZJ.png)

if you are using these images for lightbox thumbnail I would suggest d-flex rather than column system....

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will work .. now it will loop your columns as well

```html
require_once 'dbConfig.php'; 

$result = $db->query("SELECT image FROM images ORDER BY uploaded DESC"); 
?>

<?php if($result->num_rows > 0){ ?> 

    <div class="row">
    

    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" >
    <a class="lightbox">
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" width="250", " height="250">';}?>

</a>    
</div> 

<?php }else{ ?> 
    <p class="status error">Image(s) not found...</p> 
<?php } ?>  


 
</div>
```